# Superpositions with two observers

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition

This is a bit of an odd question. I'm not a physicist, so bear with me if I say something wrong.

Lets say you have some sort of quantum event where matter is in a superposition. Standing next to you is another scientist waiting to observe the results (and, in theory, collapse the suposition). You go to get a cup of coffee while your fellow scientist stays in the room. Your fellow scientist observes the result of the experiment while you are out of the room but does not tell you what the result was. There are three possible options here for when you return to the room:

1. The matter is still in a superposition for both you and the other scientist.
2. The matter is no longer in a superposition for either of you (even though you have not observed the event and have no knowledge of what happened).
3. The matter is in a superposition only to you.

So which option is it? If the answer is option 2, would that mean that we as humans have some kind of "superpower" forcing quantum superpositions to collapse as soon as we see them?

Comment: This is the [Wigner's friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner's_friend) problem.

Comment: It is option 2 but we don't have any superpowers. Drawing that conclusion is to confuse 'observer' with 'conscious observer'. It is a disturbance to the system which collapses the wavefunction, not the presence or knowledge of a conscient being. You don't need to know if your friend performed a measurement for the wavefunction to have collapsed. If he doesn't tell you he did anything, you would of course assume the superposition still exists - but you would be wrong.

Comment: @Wouter Okay, so what about an observers senses causes this disturbance to happen? Is it that the photons bouncing off this matter whether directly or indirectly interact with both your eyes and the quantum state?

Comment: @Wouter I wouldn't normally get stuck into this sort of discussion, but you sound awfully sure of yourself here so I'm going to prod a little bit :) Don't you think taking this disturbance-collapse as a physical process implies a gross non-locality to Nature? Say I have a singlet pair of spacelike separated spins. I measure the direction of spin A on Earth with my Stern-Gerlach magnets, getting the result $|\uparrow\rangle$ relative to my favourite Cartesian axis. Now spin B has collapsed to $|\downarrow\rangle$. What is the disturbance responsible for this collapse?

Comment: @MarkMitchison First off, I may have cut a few corners in trying to achieve my goal - which was to show why we don't have superpowers. Then, for the situation you sketch: if I knew a satisfactory response to that, I reckon the last paragraph in your answer would look different and I'd likely be getting a prize, no? :) As you said in your answer, entangled states are a bitch for interpretation (if you'll pardon the language). And the solution isn't clear as far as I know. As an MA student with a theoretical background, I'm particularly interested in learning more about the non-local ideas.

Comment: @Wouter You would *deserve* a prize for sure. But it would probably go to the experimentalists instead. :)

Comment: @MarkMitchison :D You're probably right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is called [Wigner's friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend). Basically the answer according to quantum mechanics is 2. If my friend makes a measurement causing collapse of the superposition, then when I return I will not see any quantum interference, so a superposition state would predict the wrong outcomes. If my friend doesn't tell me what happened in his measurement, then I must assign a [mixed state](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_state#Mixed_states), or classical probability distribution, to the system.

Whether you think this is weird or not depends on your idea about what quantum mechanics is telling you. If you think that quantum states just represent knowledge, then there is nothing weird: collapse just means updating your probability distribution when you learn new information. If you think that quantum states are physically real things, then there is no problem if the system is localised: the measurement must involve a physical interaction which changes the physical state.

The spanner in the works occurs when you deal with [entangled states](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement). Then the collapse in my lab also appears to have consequences for measurement outcomes in distant places. [Bell's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem) tells you that you cannot have both a local and realistic description of this process. If you think quantum states are only information, then you must accept that physical properties of quantum systems do not exist independently of observation. If you think quantum states are physical objects, then you must accept that the interaction in my lab had a non-local influence on the system in the distant lab. Most people like locality, so choose the former option. Particularly because the concept of locality is deeply rooted in our understanding of elementary particle physics and gravity. But the two options are not distinguishable by any currently known experiment, so the inevitable and continuous arguments between people from the two camps are pretty pointless. Nevertheless, I expect at least one person will start arguing with me over this post :)

Comment: Is the answer given here still correct?  http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=600036

Comment: @Chris It wasn't ever correct I'm afraid. Bob uses a polariser set at 90 degrees to the first diagonal polariser. If Alice performs no measurement, then the photon will never pass through Bob's polariser. If Alice has performed a measurement in the horizontal/vertical basis, the probability of the resulting photon passing Bob's diagonal polariser is 1/2. So assuming Alice does perform this measurement, Bob has a 50% chance of telling that she did when the photon passes through his polariser.

Comment: However, 1/2 of the time the photon doesn't pass and Bob is none the wiser. So there is no way for Bob to know with *certainty*, assuming that there is only one photon. If there are many photons going through an identical process then Bob can tell what Alice did with high probability by performing many measurements. Note, however, that Bob *must* know the configuration of the first diagonal polariser for this all to work.

Comment: Thanks Mark, if only Dr Chinese could provide such a nice answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that observation is a "real" thing just like quantum states are physical objects? How does one define observation in this instance without saying any physical interaction with a quantum state is some form of observation?

Comment: @Jason In short, one does not define observation in quantum mechanics. It's meaning is taken to be self-evident, a fuzziness in language that is responsible for a lot of confusion. Generally interactions between complex systems result in decoherence, which means quantum superpositions turn into classical probability distributions. The question is then how the classical probability distribution "collapses" to just one result. You still need some extra philosophical input to describe this, although this certainly seems to make more sense to me if the wavefunction is only information.

Comment: @MarkMitchison Now I feel like I'm probably getting into an endless loop of questions (I'm far too curious for my own good :P), but what counts as an interaction between such complex systems? And beyond that, what might be considered a complex system (i.e. at what point is a system considered complex)?

Comment: @Jason These ones are easier. Interactions between subsystems are well defined in quantum mechanics, they arise when the energy depends on the coordinates of more than one subsystem. E.g. the energy of two electrons depends on their distance due to the Coulomb force/interaction. So this is very intuitive. Also, there was actually no need for me to invoke the idea of complex systems, decoherence appears locally for almost any interaction. The point is that in complex systems there are so many degrees of freedom that this decoherence is effectively irreversible, while for simple systems it isn't

Comment: @MarkMitchison Okay, now I think I'm starting to understand. So how do we know that quantum states are, in fact, physical objects? Would we define them as the state of energy in a system?

Comment: @Jason "The quantum state is everything that can be known about the system". That is all QM has to say on the subject, until further notice. Notice I did *not* say that quantum states are "physical objects", I said some people think that way and some people don't. Furthermore, the distinction is philosophical only. Although see, for example, [Matt Pusey's paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.3328) addressing part of this question.